# LUIS Pattern.any entities

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Why can't you tag entities of type Pattern.any in utterances? I have cases where I want the model to try to learn the entity, but also have cases where there is a clear pattern to when this entity will occur. Is there any way to solve this use case, or the best practice to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Pattern.any is only for the Patterns, and not for example utterances in the Intents. Patterns do not learn in the sense that you mean. They are rules for matching.